# Log configuration with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an API path `api/v1`. When `api/v1` is called, I would like the log to be written to the `api.log` file (e.g., `log/api.log`). By default, it will be written to `development.log`.

```
namespace :v1 do
  post 'tests/test', to: 'tests#tests'
end
```

I want to call `v1/test/test` and have it logged to file `log/api.log`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to implement something like this http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-a-custom-logger-in-rails/